# Dotnet: Works in VSCode's OWN TERMINAL, but OMNISHARP: 'dotnet.exe' is not recognized

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-code, .net-core, windows-10

How is this possible?

- I installed .net sdk 6.0.405: `dotnet-sdk-6.0.405-win-x64.exe`
- I can in windows terminal and power shell run: `dotnet --version`: 6.0.405 ✅
- I CAN ALSO IN VSCODE IN ITS BUILTIN TERMINAL, `run: dotnet --version`: 6.0.405 ✅✅
- But in the OUTPUT tab, choosing `OmniSharp Log` from the dropdown, it says:

> [ERROR] A .NET 6 SDK for x86_64 was not found. Please install the latest x86_64 SDK from ...

I switched vscode explorer settings to use external terminal.

And this terminal setting to `command prompt`:

> Terminal › Integrated › Default Profile: Windows
> The default profile used on Windows. This setting will currently be ignored if either terminal.integrated.shell.windows or terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows are set.

I have dotnet in the PATH (and it works in terminals and in vscode's terminal)

I restarted vscode, AND REINSTALLED the dotnettools "C# for Visual Studio Code (powered by OmniSharp)" extension. I went to [the online store](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-dotnettools.csharp) and from the right column under Resources I downloaded the `ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.25.2@win32-x64.vsix` to make sure I get the right one. And restarted vscode.

I tried this setting:

> Omnisharp: Dotnet Path
> Specified the path to a dotnet installation to use when "useModernNet" is set to true, instead of the default system one. This only influences the dotnet installation to use for hosting Omnisharp itself. Example: "/home/username/mycustomdotnetdirectory".

`C:/Program Files/dotnet/sdk/6.0.405`

And this setting:

> Omnisharp: Sdk Path
> Specifies the path to a .NET SDK installation to use for project loading instead of the highest version installed. Applies when "useModernNet" is set to true. Example: /home/username/dotnet/sdks/6.0.300.

`C:/Program Files/dotnet/sdk/6.0.405`

And restarted vscode. And now it says:

> [ERROR] Error: Command failed: dotnet.exe --version
> 'dotnet.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> operable program or batch file.

What? W H A T? lol

What could be wrong? Why isn't it saying where it expected to find it and what to do to locate it? Is there a setting to specify the `dotnet.exe` path to this C# extension? Does it need always-on internet or something? Does it have DRM? Does it need Edge installed? Wtf?

I just need intellisense; and I've wasted 2h, on only microsoft-owned products.
#Microsoft 0/5 stars

Comment: [Possibly related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75323687/visual-studio-code-1-73-1-trouble-object-not-defined)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still don't know why it happens, but here's how to solve it:

The problem was from this: I like to keep all my visual studio code extensions as `.vsix` files locally in folders so I can remember and get them easily & offline. Sensible enough choice, and I had the correct `ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.25.2@win32-x64.vsix` for my platform.

But in VSCode, when I install this particular extension via VSIX, even though it succeeds, it can't find .net. If you instead install the extension "normally", ie via vscode's own download, it seems vscode does some extra configuration steps while installing, and probably sets the .net paths correctly or something. Because now it works.

So TL;DR: don't install `ms-dotnettools.csharp` via vsix, it seems bugged.

---

Would love to see an answer explaining what's wrong /  how to actually do via vsix; but I don't have any more time to debug this rn.

Comment: This did not work for me. I have the exact same error message and symptoms described in question but using the extension v1.25.7 installed from within VS Code IDE. I even tried deleting all VS Code extensions from {user}/.vscode/extensions, uninstalling VS Code and re-installing. I am using a WSL instance of VS Code as well and wonder if this could be causing problems